# Redirect Page Based on Whether the Last Element has a Specific CSS Attribute Value Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, redirect, attributes, jquery-cycle

I need to redirect a page when an image slider reaches the last image (ideally after a set time).

I have the code below sort of working but it redirects as soon as the second image is shown. Can anyone help please?

```
if ($('#mainContent ul.introScreen li img.active:last').css('display', 'block')) {
    window.location.href = "/ibp/app.php";
} else {
    //Do nothing
}
```

Thanks folks.

EDIT: I think I have an issue with my code somewhere, it seems to be cycling through just the first image. My code is below. Any idea?

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#introScreen li img.active');
    if ($active.length == 0)
        $active = $('#introScreen li img:last');
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#introScreen li img:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).addClass('active').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 1000, function () {
        $active.removeClass('active lastActive');
    });
    if ($('#introScreen li img.active:last').is(':visible')) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "/ibp/app.php";
        }, 1000);
        // 1 sec
    }
}
$(function () {
    setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
});
```

EDIT: I'm trying a different approach using the Cycle jQuery plugin with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="introScreen">
    <ul id="slides">
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/screen01-placeholder.png" alt="Screen 01 Placeholder" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("ul#slides").cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pause: 2
});
if ($('ul#slides li:last').is(':visible')) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "/ibp/app.php";
    }, 1000);
    // 1 sec
}
```

Now the images fade in to each other fine but again now the page does not redirect? Any ideas guys?

Comment: Please avoid changing your question in such a way that makes existing answers irrelevant. I've revised my answer anyhow.

Comment: iam not sure if i understood with so many changes: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/QDaxm/1/ it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is(":visible")` to check whether the element is [*visible*](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) or not:

```
if($('...:last').is(':visible')) {
...
}
```

Another variant:

```
if($('...:last:visible').length /* == 1 */) {
...
}
```

I've removed all selectors except the ones that matter. I would rather place the logic in the code that changes the slides.

## Edit 2

jQuery.cycle plugin [fires various events](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html). One of them is the `after` event that fires after a slide is displayed. Within that event you can check if it was the last slide and do whatever is necessary:

```
$("ul#slides").cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    after: function() {
        if ($(this).next().length === 0) {
            alert("Place the redirection code here");
        }
    }
});
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/QDaxm/)

Comment: Hey Thanks. I have an issue with the code still. I've edited my original post with the full code.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. I've changed the HTML to use a div#slider with all the images in it but it now again redirects when the second image loads. http://dev.garethdaine.com/ibp/

Comment: Tell a lie it's actually redirecting on the 3rd image? Weird.

Comment: can you tell us what $('... li:last').length logs? (note i removed the :visible)

Comment: You can still run a command in the console of your browser inspector tools to see what it yields

Comment: Yes, sorry now I understand. I've decided to use a different approach using the code above, which I've made an edit to but now it doesn't redirect at all. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Salman A Thank you so much. That worked a treat. I really appreciate all your help on this. I've learnt quite a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `is(':visible')`

is(':visible')` or at least do compare:

```
  if($('#mainContent ul.introScreen li img.active:last').is(':visible')) {
        window.location.href = "/ibp/app.php";
    } else {
        //Do nothing
    }
```

or at least do compare:

```
if($('#mainContent ul.introScreen li img.active:last').css('display')=='block') {
    window.location.href = "/ibp/app.php";
} else {
    //Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. I have an issue with the code still. I've edited my original post with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

`.css(string, string)` is *always* a setter. You're setting `display` of the last image to `block` and checking whether the return value of that operation (which is always the jQuery object itself, for chaining) evaluates to true (which it always will).

You need to check `.css('display') == 'block'`, or preferably `.is(':visible')`.

For a delay, use `setTimeout`.

```
if($('#mainContent ul.introScreen li img.active:last').is(':visible')) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = "/ibp/app.php";
    }, 1000); // 1 sec
}
```

Oh, and if you really want to "Do nothing", you don't need your `else` block at all.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I have an issue with the code still. I've edited my original post with the full code.